# Javascript - How do I detect when my popup window visits my site?

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, extjs

My site opens up a popup window to an external site, but at some point, the popup window will redirect to my site again.  Because of security reasons, I know I can't look at the popup window URL until it redirects to back to my site.  What I did is kept checking every second to see whether I could access the url address, and once I could, (meaning the popup window was back on my site) I stored the Url info and closed the popup.  This seems like a pretty bad way of doing it...

Is there any way to detect the window returning to my site?

Comment: I don't understand your question? How are the tags (sencha) related to your question?

Comment: Do you have control of what page on your site they are sent back to? If so, make a page with some javascript that can run to let you know it is back to your site. Then just make sure they linkback to _that_ page.

Comment: @kay Sencha is related because thats what I am working in and there might be an event handler specific to their library that works

Comment: @TheZ  I am actually currently trying to do this.. I do have control over it. Do you know what javascript I would have to write to notify my main page that the user is back on my site?

Comment: I think you should look into the `window.opener` property.

Comment: @TheZ That looks really really promising. Using it now!

Comment: If you get something working post it as an answer for others to see :)

Comment: @TheZ So I just added an eventlistener to check if I received a url from the target site.  Seeing as you basically walked me through this, you should probably post your answer about putting a script on the other page and using window.opener.  I'll accept it.  Besides, I wouldn't be able to choose my own answer and close the post for three days...:p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the linkback page for the popup then you can set up a special page just for this purpose. All you'd need to do would be to create a page with some javascript that runs to notify you that you have come full circle.

One property that popup windows have is the `window.opener` property which refers to the parent window that initially created the pop-up.

This should be a good place to start.